# javascript - open frame in new window

Tags: javascript

I have a page which is displayed in a frame as part of another site.  I want to add a link to this page which will allow the user to open the page in a new window i.e. out of the frame.  how do I do this?

I have tried using

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.href" target="_blank">Remove frame</a>
```

but this did not work and only opened a new window with the address `javascript:window.location.href`

Comment: The best solution whould be to actually put the real URL of the current page into the link.

Comment: @RoToRa they are dynamic pages so don't know the actually url

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamic"? Any dynamic creation of HTML documents (especially server-side scripts) usually provide a way to get it's own URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input onclick="javascrpt:window.open(window.location.href);" type="button" value="your value here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<a href="javascript:window.location='whereiwanttogo.html';" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it worked for me:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open(window.location.href);return true;" target="_blank">Printable version</a>
```